# Laravel Trait 'Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

HI i searched Google but did not find anything about this and i never had this error before in Laravel.

I did not modify my user model just added a `hasOne` relation.

And i keep getting this error what i am not able to solve for 2 hours now

```
Trait 'Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait' not found
```

I did not touch the model

**User model**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');


    public function metadata()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Metadata');
    }

}
```

Could someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need to upgrade to Laravel v4.2.

The Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait class wasn't introduced until v4.2. Check the [change log](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/changes.json) on github.

Check the [upgrade guides](http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade) if you do upgrade as there were a couple of other changes that may break your app.

Comment: nope i downloaded the 4.1 latest install, and the upgrade guide tells nothing about this only soft deleting trait

Comment: It isn't in v4.1 ... like i said, it was introduced from v4.2. You can confirm this by reading the [API docs](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Auth/UserTrait.html) .

Comment: @Jeemusu assuming 4.2 I don't see why you are saying that the traits are not required? As far as I know they are required (or your own implementation) in order to fulfil the `UserInterface` and `RemindableInterface` contracts. The class you posted won't work as I see it as it'll complain about methods not completed.

Comment: @WebStudent if you're on 4.1 (your composer.json file says `"laravel/framework": "4.1.*"`) then these traits (as @Jeemusu says) don't exist - you have to fill in the methods yourself. You can se [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/65db159b2d2204d091da07de351171d207b8b779/app/models/User.php) for the most up-to-date 4.1 version of the User model that includes the methods but not the traits.

Comment: @alexrussell Your correct, if I look at the 4.2 **[User Model on github](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/models/User.php)** it matches up with OP's, sorry I was going off my 4.1.2 version. :S

Comment: thanks for the reply guys, but im still going insane, placed the traits, now the User model relations do not work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279959/laravel-user-relations-stoped-working

Comment: post another question with the new problems and I will take a look.

Comment: posted link included,with older post, but i will attach it again, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279959/laravel-user-relations-stoped-working